# How to generate CDATA with XmlTextWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm using `XmlTextWriter` class in my project. i don't know, how to use CDATA in Xml. Can anyone help me?

```
objX.WriteElementString("category", c.DeepestCategoryName);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Don't use `new XmlTextWriter()`. Use `XmlWriter.Create()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by others, use `WriteCData` if you want to write a CDATA section explicitly. Here is a general-purpose extension method that I use to write a CDATA element 'automatically' if the text contains certain characters:

```
public static void WriteElementContent(this XmlWriter writer, string content)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        return;
    }

    // WriteString will happily escape any XML markup characters. However, 
    // for legibility we write content that contains certain special
    // characters as CDATA 
    const string SpecialChars = @"<>&";
    if (content.IndexOfAny(SpecialChars.ToCharArray()) != -1)
    {
        writer.WriteCData(content);
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteString(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea (necessary even more than the example above) to use CDATA if the content started or ended with white-space that you wanted to retain, or contained consecutive whitespace characters that you wanted to retain?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to.

`XmlTextWriter` will automatically escape your text.

CDATA sections can be useful when writing XML by hand to avoid escaping characters.
Since the XmlTextWriter will escape characters for you, there's no point in making a CDATA section.

If you really want to, you can call the [`WriteCData` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writecdata.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps someone, it did me.

I **had** to use an XML web service that explicitly expected a CDATA section. I wanted to do serialization of an object using `XmlSerializer`, and didn't want to bother with manually having to do `WriteCData()` every time.

Using Rich Tebb's `WriteContentElement` code (thanks for that!), I subclassed `XmlTextWriter` and overrid `WriteString(string text)` as follows:

```
public class MyXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public MyXmlTextWriter(TextWriter textWriter) : base(textWriter) { }
    public MyXmlTextWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding) { }
    public MyXmlTextWriter(string filename, Encoding encoding) : base(filename, encoding) { }
    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return;
        }

        // WriteString will happily escape any XML markup characters. However, 
        // for legibility we write content that contains certain special
        // characters as CDATA 
        const string SpecialChars = @"<>&";
        if (text.IndexOfAny(SpecialChars.ToCharArray()) != -1)
        {
            WriteCData(text);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteString(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following code, any string with 'special characters' will now be rendered as a CDATA section instead of encoded:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = new MyXmlTextWriter(memoryStream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    {                    
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Side note: I'm using a `MemoryStream` and `UTF8Encoding(false)` to get a UTF-8 encoded string without a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and the XML-tag rendered as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WriteCData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writecdata.aspx), if you want an explicit `<![CDATA[]]>` section.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Write CData block
    xmlWriter.WriteCData("<br>");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writecdata.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public static class XsdObjectSerializer {
    #region Public Methods
    public static String ToXsdSerializedXmlDocument<T>(this T t) {
        using (var customUtf8TextWriter = new CustomUtf8StringWriter()) {
            using (var customXmlTextWriter = new CustomXmlTextWriter(customUtf8TextWriter)) {
                customXmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(customXmlTextWriter, t);
            }
            var xsdSerializedXmlDocument = customUtf8TextWriter.ToString();
            return xsdSerializedXmlDocument;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Classes
    private class CustomUtf8StringWriter : StringWriter {
        public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
    }

    private class CustomXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter {
        public CustomXmlTextWriter(TextWriter textWriter) : base(textWriter) { }
        public CustomXmlTextWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding) { }
        public CustomXmlTextWriter(string filename, Encoding encoding) : base(filename, encoding) { }
        public override void WriteString(string text) {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return;

            const string SpecialChars = @"<>&";
            if (text.IndexOfAny(SpecialChars.ToCharArray()) != -1) {
                WriteCData(text);
            } else {
                base.WriteString(text);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are usually frowned upon; consider adding some context / explanations.